# sending queries to remote servers

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to create a php code that will provide all the information that we need in one place.

Some of the information that we need is on https://link

I am able to sending queries directly to it using a php form but the only trouble is it only works after someone has performed a manual search. Once someone has search for something then it works until the browser is closed.

Once a user closes the browser, then it start returning errors again.

try opening this link without doing a manual search. https://link

that would give an error, now open the first link https:// and then search for something.

now open this link again: https://searchType=singleQuery&phrase=exact&keywords=02284065

that should not give an error.

Came someone explain to me whats going on and how I can work around this?

Thanks.

edit:
I do not have access to the code on the remote server. on my end I am currently using

```
    <?php
     echo file_get_contents(searchType=singleQuery&phrase=exact&keywords=02284065");
 ?>
```

to test out. once I solve this problem then I would develop the code further.

edit: this is what I have so far, this returns the form but does not submit the form.

```
<?php
$url='https:/';
$keywords ='';
$ch = curl_init() ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
$data = array(
'keywords' => "$keywords",
'Search' => 'submit'
);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
$output = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo "$output\n";
?>
```

Comment: Please provide code so we can look into actual problem and not guess what it could be.

Comment: Please provide more info on the errors

Comment: see edit above. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite likely that you're trying to use this service in an improper way. These days, many portals just accept queries (and POST requests, to be more precise) from a "whitelist" of clients. A client in this whitelist could be the website itself, or an authorized mobile app.

You should learn something about the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), as a "basic" of what we're talking about.

Usually, it's up to the site owner deciding who will be able to query the server, and who will not.

**Solution:** You should contact the **healthinfo.moh.gov.on.ca** administrators and ask them if they have some APIs, in order to get your data in a more structured and correct way.

EDIT: probably you can do your search after a manual one on the website because of some session data. After that, the session expires and you can't continue.

Comment: I will try but its a government website, would be surprised if they are able to provide any helpful information. You think its a cookie that they place after a successful search that allows my code to work until the browser is closed?

Comment: I am not talking about cookies, but sessions. Different concepts! :) Also, you can stumble upon many legal issues if you try to take government data without the right permissions... pay attention!

Comment: I would definitely ask for permission. right now just testing feasibility. thanks for all your help.

Comment: Good luck with your project @rm65453 :)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Francesco - esp. about the misuse and contacting the provider - but would add, for educational purposes:

Try using a cURL request instead of file_get_contents.

[php doc examples](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)

A snippet I **happen** to be working with right now:

```
public function triggerMessage(Contact $tocontact, $msgid)
{
  $msgurl = 'https://www.server.com/t/?' . $msgid;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $msgurl);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count(get_object_vars($tocontact)));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->contactToUrlParams($tocontact));
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Just sent an email to the provider. Would it be possible to send in a dummy query in the background using curl before the actual code is run in php? that would essentially solve my problem.

Comment: curl can certainly be run from the cli. if you happen to be on linux: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/curl-examples/

Comment: am running php on a windows server 2008 r2. the php_curl extension is enabled. not sure if that helps.

Comment: if you type `curl` into the cli, what does it say? it'll be either something about how you don't have the curl command, or something about curl's usage. It it's the latter, you're good. Wish I could be more help there - I'm strictly linux, though, so don't know much about how windows packages work

Comment: I looked it up - seems like curl from the windows cli is terribly awkward. 
You can always write a one-off procedural php file that does it, then call it from the command-line like `php -f somefile.php` 
or run php in interactive mode with `php -a`

Comment: In linux, I can run `php -f somefile.php > fileoutput.txt` to catch its output. Surely, windows has something like that?

Comment: will be working on this tonight. hopefully something works out.

Comment: am able to at least get the form data, it is not submitting the data as I thought it would. please see above.

Comment: Study up on curl a little more. You're sending a POST request to a GET service. They have different requirements.

Comment: Thanks. Looking into that now.

Comment: In chrome, you can inspect the http request to see precisely what data is sent with the headers. Going back to the original 'unintended use' issue, it's very likely that your endpoint has a layer of protection against this sort of access. You'll be able to tell from the headers: if there's a field something like 'authorize' or 'token' or really anything other than your query (esp. if it looks like md5 or sha string), then the endpoint is protected.

Comment: there is a cookie in the heading.